# Objective C compiler on Windows 8

Tags: objective-c

I have successfully installed all what is needed to compile Objective C code on Windows 8 i.e

> 1. GNUstep MSYS subsystem
> 2. GNUstep Core
> 3. GNUstep Devel

I need help about how to start compiling my code. Lets say i have the following code chunk:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
NSLog (@"Programming is fun!");
}
return 0;
}
```

I saved this code as hello.m in E:/ . I then tried opening his file in GNU windows shell but it throws error. Below is screenshot attached:[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wDBl.jpg)

Please also note that the installation root directory for GNU files is C:/

Answer (score 2):

You have to compile your program to run it. Just typing its name into the terminal isn't sufficient; try:

```
gcc -objc hello.m -o hello.exe
./hello.exe
```

Comment: i tried writing gcc -objc hello.m -o hello.exe to the shell but its throwing error: hello.m:1:34: fatal error: fatal error foundation/foundation.h: no such file or directory

Comment: Please also note that the installation root directory for GNU files is C:\ i.e  C:\GNUstep and C:\MinGW